# get value from radio button once checked to tally up final score

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am making a multiple choice quiz with radio buttons and i want to get value form radio button once its checked and give final score at end. for example "1 out of 5 correct".

> > Blockquote
>
> ```js
> > 
> >     $(document).ready(function() {
> >       var counter = 0;
> >       var score = 0;
> > 
> > 
> >       var quizQuestions = [{
> >         question: "In what year was America founded ?",
> >         choices: ["1775", "1776", "1801", "1492"],
> >         answer: 1
> >       }, {
> >         question: "Who did not sign the Declaration of Independence ?",
> >         choices: ["George Wasington", "Ben Franklin", "John Hancock", "Thomas Jefferson"],
> >         answer: 0
> >       }, {
> >         question: "Who was the only president to serve more than two terms?",
> >         choices: ["George Washington", "Woodrow Wilson", "Franklin Delano Roosevelt", "James Madison"],
> >         answer: 2
> >       }, {
> >         question: "In what year did America land on the moon ?",
> >         choices: ["1969", "1965", "1970", "1968"],
> >         answer: 0
> >       }, {
> >         question: "Which country did America buy the Louisiana Purchase from ?",
> >         choices: ["England", "Spain", "Germany", "France"],
> >         answer: 3
> >       }]
> > 
> >       $("#start").click(function() {
> >         $("#start").hide()
> >         $("#next").show()
> >       })
> > 
> >       $("#next").on("click", function() {
> > 
> >         $(".choices, .questions").empty();
> > 
> >         function incrementCounter() {
> >           $("#count").text(counter);
> >         };
> > 
> >         $(".questions").append("<h2>" + quizQuestions[counter].question + "</h2>")
> > 
> >         for (var i = 0; i < quizQuestions[counter].choices.length; i += 1) {
> >           $(".choices").append("<ul>" + "<input type='radio'/>" + quizQuestions[counter].choices[i] + "</ul>")
> >         }
> > 
> >         incrementCounter();
> >         counter++
> > 
> >       })
> > 
> > 
> >     });
> > 
> >
> ```
>
> ```css
> > 
> >     body {
> >       background-image: url("../img/american-flag.jpg");
> >       background-repeat: no-repeat;
> >       background-size: 100% 100%;
> >     }
> >     html,
> >     body {
> >       min-height: 100%;
> >     }
> >     .quiz-app {
> >       position: relative;
> >       width: 400px;
> >       height: 400px;
> >       background-color: white;
> >       border-style: solid;
> >       margin: 0 auto;
> >       top: 200px;
> >       text-align: center;
> >     }
> >     h1 {
> >       color: orange;
> >     }
> >     #start {
> >       margin-top: 70px;
> >       width: 70px;
> >       border-radius: 5px;
> >       bottom: 150px;
> >     }
> >     #next {
> >       display: none;
> >       margin-top: 70px;
> >       width: 70px;
> >       border-radius: 5px;
> >       bottom: 150px;
> >     }
> >     .questions {
> >       text-align: center;
> >       margin-left: 25px;
> >       margin: 0 auto;
> >       bottom: 120px;
> >       color: red;
> >     }
> >     .choices {
> >       display: block;
> >       bottom: 100px;
> >     }
> >     #count {
> >       width: 50px;
> >       height: 20px;
> >       text-align: bottom;
> >     }
> > 
> >
> ```
>
> ```html
> > 
> >     <!DOCTYPE html>
> >     <html>
> > 
> >     <head>
> >       <meta charset="UTF-8">
> >       <title>Quiz Time</title>
> >       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.js"
> > charset="utf-8"></script>
> >       <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
> >       <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
> >       <script src="js/app.js"></script>
> >       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
> >     </head>
> > 
> >     <body>
> >       <!--______________________________________________________BEGIN APP-->
> >       <div class="quiz-app">
> >         <h1 class="title">History Quiz</h1>
> > 
> >         <div class="questions"></div>
> > 
> >         <div class="choices">
> >         </div>
> > 
> >         <button id="start">Start</button>
> >         <button id="next">Next</button>
> >         <span id="count"></span>
> >       </div>
> > 
> >     </body>
> >     <!--______________________________________________________END APP-->
> > 
> >     </html>
> > 
> >
> ```

Comment: You're almost there. You need to add a name attribute to each radio button (must be same for each choice in a question, eg q1) and a value attribute to each radio took. Add a click handler to the next button which checks which radio is selected and whether its the correct answer, and increments the score if so. BTW you should surround your radios with <li> tags.

Comment: thank you so much for your time, how would i go about this? any further hints or example would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$(".choices input:radio").on("click", function () {
    alert('test');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, i am new to this where would i insert this in my code to make it function? sorry to ask such an amateur question.